# Can list files with json and output in html table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

This is my code in php, js and html but if i clicked the button, didn't show the table with files.

PHP CODE

```
<?php

$nombre_archivo = $_FILES['archivo1']['name']; 


  if ($_FILES["archivo1"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo $_FILES["archivo1"]["error"] . "";
  } else {
    if (file_exists("files/" . $_FILES["archivo1"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["archivo1"]["name"] . " ya existe. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo1"]["tmp_name"], "files/" . $_FILES["archivo1"]["name"]);

            $dir=opendir("files/");
            $carpeta =  @scandir("files/");
            $cantarch = count($carpeta);
            $i= 0;
                if ($cantarch > 2){ //comprueba que hay archivos    
                  while ($cantarch > $i ){    //muestra el vector  
                    if (2 > $i ) {
                           $i++;
                    } else {
                           $files_array[] = array('nombre' => $file);
                           $i++;
                    }
                  }
                }
         $return_array = array('nombre' => $files_array );$files_array;

                print json_encode($return_array);

      }
    }
```

JS CODE

```
$(function(){
    $("#uploadAjax").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("uploadAjax"));
        formData.append("dato", "valor");

        $.ajax({
            url: "recibe.php",
            type: "post",
            data: formData, 
            dataType: "json", 
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false, 
            success: function(data) {

                var html='';
                if (data.length > 0) {            
                    $.each(data, function(i,item){ 

                                                html+= '<tr>'
                                                html+='<td>'+item+'</td>'
                                                html+='<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></button></td>'
                                                html+='<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button></td>'
                                                html+='<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button></td>'
                                                html+='</tr>'
                    });
                }

                if (var html == '') {
                                    html = '<tr><td colspan="4">No se encontraron registros..</td></tr>';
                }

                $("#tabla tbody").html(html);

                    }                     
            });            
        });
    }
```

Please i need this for list directories and make a playlist of video files.

Comment: what do you see in console against the ajax request ? what is in the response tab

Comment: I can see anything only see thead but the body isnt appeared. the file upload but the table isnt updated

Comment: check `console.log(data.length,data)` before the check in the `success` callback what does it show you ?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1 this show

Comment: you should add it in the `succes` callback how come it says `data` is not defined ?

Comment: I see a typo: Near the bottom of your code, at the "if..." line, you do not need `var` in front of html

Comment: already change that, but now the console say that 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list' when there is nothing else

Comment: console.log isn't says anything but the files was uploaded